# Учусь работать с чтением и записью данных в файлы

Tags: c++, fstream

пишу программу которая по нажатию кнопки сохраняет отправленный текст или считывает сохраненный текст

я вписываю предложения а сохраняется в файле только символы до пробела

вот весь код:

```
#include "Zag.h"
int read(std::string& path)
{
    std::fstream read;
    read.open(path, std::fstream::in| std::fstream::app);
    if (!read.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Ошибка открытия файла";
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::string out;
        while (!read.eof())
        {
    
            out = "";
            std::getline(read, out);
            std::cout << out<<std::endl;
    
        }
    }
}   
void write(std::string &path)
{
    std::fstream write;
    write.open(path, std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
    if (!write.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Ошибка открытия файла!\n";
    }
    else
    {

        SetConsoleCP(1251);
        std::string file;
        std::cin>>file;
        write << file<<"\n";
            
        SetConsoleCP(866);
    }
    std::cout << "Текст сохранен!";
}
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    std::string path = "filya.txt";
    std::cout << "Нажмите w или W если хотите записать текст в файл:\nнажмите R или r если хотите прочитать текст сохраненный в файле:\n";
    char key; key = _getch();
    switch (key)
    {
    case'w':case 'W':
        std::cout << "напишите текст текст:\n";
        write(path);
        break;
    case 'R':
    case 'r':
        std::cout << "Ваш текст:\n";
        read(path);
        break;
    }
}
```

а вот подключаемый заголовок

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
```

вот к примеру введем сообщение : Привет Мир!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а в итоге сохраняется :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Код приводите форматированным текстом

Comment: `std::string file;          std::cin>>file;` С чего вы решили, что должна читаться вся строка, а не первое слово? (сначала читайте руководство по языку С++, а уже потом пишите программы)

Comment: в заголовке должно быть краткое описание твоей проблемы, а не твоя автобиография

Comment: Комментарий про заголовок все еще актуален. [ask]